# Scraping main image rather than Thumbnail Image

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the image from [here](https://phys.org/earth-news/) My code for scraping the image is.

```
import requests

root_tag=["article", {"class":"sorted-article"}]
image_tag=["img",{"":""},"src"]
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("https://phys.org/earth-news/", headers=headers)
webContent = response.content

for div in all_tab_data:
    image_url = None
    div_img = str(div)
    match = re.search(r"(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg)", div_img)
    if match!=None:
        image_url = match.group(0)
    else:
        image_url = div.find(image_tag[0],image_tag[1]).get(image_tag[2])
    if image_url!=None:
        if image_url[0] == '/' and image_url[1] != '/':
            image_url = main_url + image_url
```

My output of image url is [output_url](https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/175u/2020/biofuels.jpg) but the actual url for the image is [actual_url](https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/biofuels.jpg) . how can i scrape the the main image?

Comment: `image_url.replace("175u","800")`

Comment: `actual_url` is absent in source code. You need to implement loop to iterate through all news links (<a `class="news-link" ...>`), do `session.get(link)` and scrape URL of the picture

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA But what if tomorrow then change it to 600 so this is temporary solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `beautifulsoup` to scrape all the news content to get the image:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get("https://phys.org/earth-news/").text, "lxml")
    news_list = [news_div.get("href") for news_div in soup.select('.news-link')]
    for url in news_list:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, "lxml")
        img = soup.select_one(".article-img")
        if img:
            print(url, img.select_one('img').get("src"))
        else:
            print(url, "This news doesn't contain image")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeautifulSoup` to extract image links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://phys.org/earth-news/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    
for img in soup.select('.sorted-article img[data-src]'):
    print( img['data-src'].replace('/175u/', '/800/') )
```

Prints:

```
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/biofuels.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/waterscarcity.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/soilerosion.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/hydropowerdam.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/flood.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2018/1-emissions.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/globalforest.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/fleeingthecl.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/watersecurity.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/2-water.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/japaneseexpe.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/6-scientistsco.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/housescollap.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/soil.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/32-researcherst.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/2-nasatracking.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/thelargersec.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/4-nasasterrasa.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/howtorecycle.jpg
https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2020/newtoolstrac.jpg
```

Comment: this will work but what if they change 800 to some other value . i have to run it everyday

Comment: @NoobCoder Then you can open each article and scrape image from there. But from experience, this kind of changes aren't often.